# nitrous webIDE - console scroll option

Tags: nitrousio

My stack trace is big enough that even fullscreen for the Console doesn't get me to the initial lines.
Is there a way I can scroll up the console lines to be able to see the initial lines?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If Ctrl + Up/Down doesn't work for you, you can also use Shift + PageUp/PageDown. I think the Ctrl + Up/Down option only works on Macs but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem with scrolling in their console, and what worked for me most of the time (depending on what command was issued) was outputting the results to a log file.

For example: `rails s > rails.log`

Then I just open the log file and scroll through it. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Actually .. I just found an article that stated you can use CTRL + Up/Down arrow keys... and it works. So there are two options for you!

Comment: When I try CTRL + Up/Down arrow keys the console simply copies the previous console command, this doesn't work for me.